# How to read a binary column data into spark dataframe?

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to read a table from SqlServer which has one column: travel_CDE of datatype: `binary(8)`.
This is how the source data looks like:

```
select * from sourcetable=>
location    type_code   family  travel_CDE
Asia        Landlocked  Terrain 0xD9F21933D5346766
```

Below is my read statement:

```
val dataframe = spark.read.format("jdbc")
.option("url", s"jdbc:sqlserver://url:port;DatabaseName=databasename")
.option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
.option("user", "username")
.option("password", "password")
.option("dbtable", tablename)
.option("partitionColumn", partitionColumn)
.option("numPartitions", numPartitions)
.option("lowerBound", 1)
.option("upperBound", upperBound)
.option("fetchsize", 100)
.load()
```

When I print the schema of the dataframe, I see that the column is being read in binary datatype:

```
scala> dataframe.printSchema()
root
 |-- location: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type_code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- family: string (nullable = true)
 |-- travel_CDE: binary (nullable = true)
```

But when I read the data inside of my spark dataframe, I see data being represented in a different format for the column `travel_CDE`.
Example:

```
scala> dataframe.select("travel_CDE").take(1)
res11: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([[B@a4a0ce])
```

So I thought spark reading data in its own format and I took that column out and re-applied a schema of binary datatype as below.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, BinaryType}
val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("bintype", BinaryType, true)))
val bincolDF = dataframe.select("travel_CDE")
val bindColtypeDF = spark.createDataFrame(bincolDF.rdd, schema)
```

But even after applying BinaryType on that column, I still see the same format of data as earlier.

```
scala> bindtype.take(1)
res9: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([[B@1d48ff1])
```

I am saving this dataframe into big query and I see the same format (wrong data format) there as well.
Below is how I am doing it.

```
dataframe.write.format("bigquery").option("table", s"Bigquery_table_name").mode("overwrite").save()
```

Could anyone let me know what should I do to read the source data properly in a way that Spark reads it in the same format.
Is it even possible to do it while reading the data or should I convert the column after reading data into dataframe ?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you do `df.show(false)` you should be able to see the data in the original format as a byte array. Doing `take` will result in a conversion to the Scala binary type, which has a different representation.

Comment: I see your point. But I am saving my dataframe into a bigquery table. I certainly can't use dataframe.show(false). WHat should I do in such scenario ?